# system.out redirection to jfx fextfield not showing scandinavian characters

Tags: java, encoding, byte, outputstream, printstream

I've been scratching my head for a few days now trying to figure out how to correctly encode scandinavian characters for use in a text field

These three characters: Æ Ø Å ( æ ø å) show up as ���.
meaning that the running this code

```
System.out.println("øst");
```

prints"�st"
. and i have no idea why.

Here's the code where i redirect the System.out to a printstream.

```
System.setProperty("user.language", "da");
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            appendConsole(new String(new byte[]{(byte)b}, "UTF-8"));
        }
    };
    PrintStream ps;
    try {
        ps = new PrintStream(out, true, "UTF-8");
        System.setOut(ps);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

If anyone has a solution to this problem, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to not cast the int to a byte to a string, but to a char. Does that work?

Comment: nah, exactly the same result, unfortunately :/

Comment: that's actually where i started, casting to byte and using the string constructor was my attempt at fixing it :)

Comment: get rid of this `new String(...);`, this is very resourcive (?) :D
what about converting your special chars to unicode chars?
e.g. `ø` would be transformed into `\u00f8`

(`System.out.println("\u00f8st");`)

Answer (score 0):

When those characters are encoded as UTF-8, they each require two bytes.  For example, Æ in UTF-8 is `{ (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x86 }`.  You cannot construct a String from just one of the bytes;  both bytes are required to form a valid UTF-8 sequence.

You'll need to accumulate bytes until you have enough to form a full UTF-8 sequence, then create a String from that.  ByteBuffer and CharsetDecoder are made for that:

```
// A UTF-8 sequence for a single character is at most 4 bytes long.
private final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

private final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();

@Override
public void write(int b)
throws IOException {

    buffer.put((byte) b);

    int size = buffer.position();
    int first = buffer.get(0) & 0xff;
    if (size == 4 ||
        (first >= 0xe0 && size == 3) ||
        (first >= 0xc0 && size == 2) ||
        first < 0x80) {

        buffer.flip();
        appendConsole(decoder.decode(buffer).toString());
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```